# Correct User Logged In, but Sitecore.Context.User Returns extranet\Anonymous and IsAuthenticated is False

Tags: identity-server, login, context-user

I'm working with Sitecore 10 and encountering a peculiar issue with user authentication. On the Sitecore login page, the correct logged-in user's name is displayed in the top right corner, indicating a successful login. However, in my code, when I check `Sitecore.Context.User.Name`, it returns `extranet\Anonymous`, and `Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated` is `false`.

```
public class ValidateUserSession : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            
            using (new SecurityDisabler())
            {
                // Check if Context and Context.Item are not null
                if (Sitecore.Context.Item != null)
                {
                    // Log the current user information
                    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("User: " + Sitecore.Context.User.Name, this);
                    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Is Authenticated: " + Sitecore.Context.IsLoggedIn, this);

                    // Check if the user is not authenticated and if authentication is required
                    if (!Sitecore.Context.IsLoggedIn && Sitecore.Context.Item["Is Authentication Required"] == "1")
                    {
                        // Get the absolute URL of the current request
                        string returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

                        // Construct the login URL and append the return URL
                        string loginPageUrl = $"/sitecore/login?returnUrl={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl)}";
                        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info($"Redirecting to: {loginPageUrl}", this);

                        // Redirect to the login page
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(loginPageUrl, false);
                        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Error in RequireSSOLoginProcessor", ex, this);
        }
    }

}
```

The config is

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <httpRequestBegin>
                <processor type="ProjectName.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Pipelines.ValidateUserSession, ProjectName.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
            </httpRequestBegin>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you're using `SecurityDisabler` earlier in your code?

Comment: no I haven't use that

Comment: And when do you call your code? Is it on some page? Is it a pipeline processor (which pipeline)?

Comment: @MarekMusielak Didn't work with the SecurityDisabler as well. I have updated the code and the config is included as well. Please refresh the page.

Comment: Sorry, the issue is still there